# Possible return types for an ArrayList in Angular6? Do invalid return types cause the .Subscribe function to be undefined?

Tags: html, arraylist, angular6, ngfor

The .subscribe promise is undefined following a successful API call. The API is returning a JSON Array List like so;

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "matches": [
        {
            "prop1": "string,
            "prop2": "string,
        },
        {
            "prop1": "string,
            "prop2": "string,
        },
    }
]
```

The .ts file requests a return type of `Fixture[]`, and the Fixture object contains an Array of objects.

```
export class FixtureComponent {
  public fixtures: Fixture[];

  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {

    http.get<Fixture[]>(baseUrl + 'api/Fixture/').subscribe(result => {
      this.fixtures = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }
}

interface Fixture {
  id: number;
  match: Match;
  matches: Array<Match>;
}

interface Match {
  id: number,
  homeClub: string;
  awayClub: string;
  date: Date;
}
```

I believe the problem to be with `Fixture[]` not being an appropriate type, but when I try to change it to a more suitable type definition, I have indexing errors, as if I'm trying to use another object to index the array.

I would expect to return an Array List that I will display using nested `*NgFor` in the DOM.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Edit:

Error in `result`: Unexpected end of input.

Comment: This feels like an A/B problem where you are trying to render `fixtures` before the API call returns. What's the actual error produced?

Comment: There is no actual error, the first place a problem arises is `subscribe`is undefined. The console is clear and `error` is also null. I had data coming through before I changed the layout of the fixture model in the middle tier.

Comment: The result produces a syntax error: _unexpected end of input._

Comment: Is the server response properly formed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that was needed was to change `Fixture[]` to `Fixture`, in all instances in the component.ts

Working well.